# Jasmine Unit Test failing when ran with all tests, succeeds when ran in isolation

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I have an angular 8 project and have a basic out of the box "should create" unit test failing with an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of null thrown". Problem is that this test succeeds if ran in isolation but fails when run with all the other unit tests for the project. Also the component that is being created in the unit test does not contain any forEach functions.

spec.ts in question

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { SubheaderComponent } from './subheader.component';
import { requiredTestModules } from '../../testing/import.helpers';
import { ApplicationInsightsService } from '../../services/application-insight/app-insight.service';

describe('SubheaderComponent', () => {
  let component: SubheaderComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<SubheaderComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ SubheaderComponent ],
      imports: [
        requiredTestModules
      ],
      providers: [ApplicationInsightsService]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SubheaderComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

});
```

unrealted other components using forEach code:

component.ts

```
    console.log(selectedInvoices);
    this.selectedInvoices = selectedInvoices;
    let subtotal = 0;
    this.selectedInvoices.forEach((selectedInvoice) => {
    subtotal = +subtotal + +selectedInvoice.paymentAmt;
    });
    this.Subtotal =  subtotal;
    this.fee = this.feePercent / 100 * this.Subtotal;
    this.totalPayment = this.Subtotal + this.fee;
    console.log(this.selectedInvoices);
```

I do have other components using forEach but the unit tests that hit those forEach() succeed both in isolation and with run all.

Any help/suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you post the code where `forEach` is been used in component.ts file?

Comment: I have faced the same issue earlier, check commenting out the forEach code. All the tests would work fine, both when all tests run at once as well as in isolation.

Comment: Please post test file containing forEach.

Comment: per @ArchitGarg i commented out component2's forEach for the selectedInvoices and the unit test succeeds but not sure how to fix that

Comment: Probably you have a test that is causing an unhandled promise rejection, or throwing an error in a callback, that runs before; and then your failing test fails due to that error. Or maybe not. This situations are really bad to debug. This article about those scenarios maybe will help you a bit: https://blog.cloudboost.io/javascript-asynchronous-testing-gotchas-ac7e5c39257

Comment: When you were running all tests together, which test (containing for each) out of three you posted was running just before this component.

Comment: component2 test, It is a similar "should create" test as the one that is failing

Comment: you can debug in chrome browser and see how many times this.selectedInvoices.forEach is executed and at time of which test's execution its value is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the forEach that is causing the error is being called in the component test before the one that is failing. Adding a null check makes my test succeed.

updated component.ts code:

```
    if (this.selectedInvoices) {
      this.selectedInvoices = selectedInvoices;
      let subtotal = 0;
      this.selectedInvoices.forEach((selectedInvoice) => {
      subtotal = +subtotal + +selectedInvoice.paymentAmt;
      });
      this.Subtotal =  subtotal;
      this.convenienceFee = this.convenienceFeePercent / 100 * this.Subtotal;
      this.totalPayment = this.Subtotal + this.convenienceFee;
      console.log(this.selectedInvoices);
    }
```

Seems pretty difficult to debug if error is being thrown for different component than where the error exists but that sounds like a larger karma problem. Thanks @Archit Garg for the help.